# Geforce MX 330 graphics card

Tags: hardware

Does anybody know if this model (GeForce mx330) graphics card is supported to work with Blender?
I did not find this specific model on the list provided on Blender's requirements webpage.
and can I count on it for handling medium expectations? (I will try to avoid high poly, simulations, or renderings on this system as much as possible).
Thank you!

PS The graphics card is mounted on [this laptop](https://laptopmedia.com/laptop-specs/acer-aspire-3-a315-57g/): Aspire 3 A315-57G-37M9. Any comments on the laptop are welcome as well:)))))

Comment: Blender 2.93 requires a graphics card with OpenGL 3.3 support. The GeForce MX330 supports OpenGL 4.6. It should work.

Comment: @Blunder  Thanks a lot!